# Creating filterable selectbox attribute using SOAP API v2

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, api

I am creating attributes using the Magento SOAP API V2, and need a few filterable attributes. I am using the following array:

```
$array = array(
    "attribute_code" => "testattribute",
    "frontend_input" => "select",   
    "scope" => "store", 
    "default_value" => "",
    "is_unique" => 0,
    "is_required" => 0,
    "apply_to" => "",
    "is_configurable" => 0,
    "is_searchable" => 0,
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
    "is_comparable" => 0,
    "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 1,
    "is_visible_on_front" => 1,
    "used_in_product_listing" => 1,
    "additional_fields" => array(
        "is_filterable" => 1, 
        "is_filterable_in_search" => 1, 
        "position" => 0, 
        "used_for_sort_by" => 0
    ),
    "frontend_label" => array(
        array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "This"), 
        array("store_id" => "1", "label" => "That")
    )
);

$client->catalogProductAttributeCreate($session, $array);
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.create.html), this should work. It does create a select attribute, but does not make it filterable. To make it filterable i still have to do it manually in Magento. I can do this by hand, and that won't be a big problem, but it is strange that this doesn't work and I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if this is an actual bug.

Comment: Not an answer, but the method  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api::create`` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Api.php` is where this API call is handled.  Some debugging in there might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array should look like this:

```
$array = array(
    "attribute_code" => "testattribute",
    "frontend_input" => "select",   
    "scope" => "store", 
    "default_value" => "",
    "is_unique" => 0,
    "is_required" => 0,
    "apply_to" => "",
    "is_configurable" => 0,
    "is_searchable" => 0,
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
    "is_comparable" => 0,
    "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 1,
    "is_visible_on_front" => 1,
    "used_in_product_listing" => 1,
    "additional_fields" => array(
        array('key'=>'is_filterable', 'value'=>1),
        array('key'=>'is_filterable_in_search', 'value'=>1),
        array('key'=>'position', 'value'=>0),
        array('key'=>'used_for_sort_by', 'value'=>0)
    ),
    "frontend_label" => array(
        array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "This"), 
        array("store_id" => "1", "label" => "That")
    )
);
```

For some reason the `additional_fields` must be passed as an array of arrays. The lower level array must have 2 elements: `key` & `value`.
If you don't like this method you can extend the wsdl to be able to pass the attribute `is_filtrable` (and others) just like `is_searchable`.
You can do this by creating a new module. Let's call it `Easylife_Catalog` with the following files.
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeEntityToCreate">
                <all>
                    <element name="is_filterable" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="is_filterable_in_search" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="position" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="used_for_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeEntityToUpdate">
                <all>
                    <element name="is_filterable" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="is_filterable_in_search" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="position" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="used_for_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

After creating this module you will be able to pass the attribute create array like this:

```
$array = array(
    "attribute_code" => "testattribute",
    "frontend_input" => "select",   
    "scope" => "store", 
    "default_value" => "",
    "is_unique" => 0,
    "is_required" => 0,
    "apply_to" => "",
    "is_configurable" => 0,
    "is_searchable" => 0,
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
    "is_comparable" => 0,
    "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 1,
    "is_visible_on_front" => 1,
    "used_in_product_listing" => 1,
    "is_filterable" => 1, 
    "is_filterable_in_search" => 1, 
    "position" => 0, 
    "used_for_sort_by" => 0
    "frontend_label" => array(
        array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "This"), 
        array("store_id" => "1", "label" => "That")
    )
);
```

If you want to use WSI Complience you will need an additional file
`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/wsi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
             targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="catalogProductAttributeEntityToCreate">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="is_filterable" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="is_filterable_in_search" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="position" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />
                    <xsd:element name="used_for_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

`catalogProductAttributeEntityToUpdate` seams to be missing in WSI complience.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I only needed the first solution though, but thanks for your extended answer! It will sure help people in the future :)